# Which type of handle bars are best for off-road & road use? 

Tags: mountain-bike, handlebars, parts

There are quite a lot of types of bars. Some best bit for aerodynamics, some best fit for control, some offer significant amount of positions.

I am looking to change my handlebars to the best fit type for both off-road rides which should offer a lot of control of bike and for road use, provide variety of positions, to gain aerodynamic form.

I was using a curved handle bars (also referred too as raised bars) before, it provide a lot of control over turn, but except that it was fine.

And does the width of the bar affect riding?

Comment: What sort of bike? What sort of on-road and off-road riding? The answers are quite different for (say) a suspended mountain bike, a touring bike and a road-racing bike.

Comment: @moz, its a MTB. I am not sure what you mean by suspended or not suspended.

Comment: A 'suspended' bike is a bike which [has bicycle suspension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicycle_suspension).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best handlebars for on/off-road MTB use are made of unobtainium:

[image: Scott AT4]

They offer four hand positions including an acceptable aero tuck. The double bar also acts as a hand-shield. The loop at the front is useful for carrying shopping small distances. The total width is narrow enough to squeeze through gaps in traffic, hands protected so long as not using the bar-end position. You get 2x 'dashboard' for mounting lights etc.

The Scott AT4 was made by the earlier incarnation of 'Scott' and they have no  interest in making them now. The alloy is some last-forever furniture alloy so keep your eyes peeled on ebay for some.

Comment: Any other types which is abundantly available?

Comment: Plain, boring riser bars. You can also get a mini-tri bar and attach it to them to get an extra position for aero tuck: https://www.wiggle.co.uk/profile-t2-draft-legal-aero-bars/ and combine with conventional bar-ends e.g. http://www.wiggle.co.uk/bbb-bbe-16-ergosticks-mtb-bar-ends/. This will have a few more bolts to creak than the AT4 solution but that is progress for you!

Comment: These days touring bars/butterfly bars do much the same job: http://www.vwvagabonds.com/Bike/BikeHandlebars.html  But the AT4's were a brilliant bar. Mine were stolen by some 'tard with a 5mm allen key and more time than ethics.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to as @Mathew pointed out, you can get some [bullhorn handlebars](http://www.statebicycle.com/product_p/bullhornslv.htm).  I got some similar to ones in the link above, but their curve inward at the end, to look more like the ones in @Mathew's post with the middle front section cut out.  Putting your hands in the front section allows you to be in almost a complete tuck position, while the bars are wide enough to give you plenty of balance on the trials.  I use bars like this exclusively on the road, as I find that they provide many different hand positions, allowing me to lessen fatigue.

Answer (score -1):

The two types of riding are quite different in terms of technique, and the bars developed for both over many years are quite different.
Standard road bars, the so-called "drop" bars, have evolved over a century and offer a variety of hand positions for efficient operation under all conditions encountered on the road.
Folks who "don't like to ride bent over" are doing it wrong.

Mountain-bike or off-road bars vary largely by width; riders who spend a lot of time on tight, woodsy singletrack may prefer a narrower bar, those who ride wide-open trails with a lot of sand and such may like a wider bar.  Other than that.. It's a matter of fit and comfort.   A slight "rise" may be more comfortable, and a slight "pull-back" may ease strain on wrists.

Comment: -1 for "Folks who "don't like to ride bent over" are doing it wrong." There are people who can't ride that way for one reason or another, and others who just find it painful to some degree.